# Get the index of Item selected in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, indexing

I've been searching for about an hour already and couldn't find a best solution.
I am migrating from VB.NET to C# Forms and to C# WPF.
Never mind that...
so I use this code for C# forms and it works, but not in C# WPF

```
 if (ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                for (lcount = 0; lcount <= ListView1.Items.Count - 1; lcount++)
                {
                    if (ListView1.Items[lcount].Selected == true)
                    {
                        var2 = lcount;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

this is the way I want to get the index of the item clicked in listbox.
I have the error in .SELECTED

please help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can get `SelectedIndex` from listView. No need to traverse over all items because as per your code you seems to be interested in index of any selected item.

```
var2 = ListView1.SelectedIndex;
```

OR

simply this will work if interested in only first index:

```
if (lst.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    var2 = lst.Items.IndexOf(lst.SelectedItems[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using the .NET Compact Framework, `SelectedIndex` is not supported. For a general solution, I prefer `SelectedIndices`:

```
ListView.SelectedIndexCollection indices = lst.SelectedIndices;
if (indices.Count > 0)
{
    // Do something with indices[0]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For Visual Studio 2015, `SelectedIndex` does not seem to be available. Instead, you can use `SelectedIndices[x]` where `x=0` will give you the first selected item:

```
listView.SelectedIndices[0]
```

You can also set the `MultipleSelect` property to `false` to only allow one item to be selected at a time.

Comment: It's available in WPF, and this is a WPF question. Perhaps you're in winforms.

Answer (score 4):

It can return NULL. Also the SelectedIndexChanged event can be FIRED TWICE. And the first time, there nothing selected yet.

So the only safe way to find it is like this:

```
    private void lv1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lv1.FocusedItem == null) return;
        int p = lv1.FocusedItem.Index;
```

... now int p has the correct value...

Answer (score 2):

```
sColl.Clear();
string item = String.Empty;

if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listView1.SelectedItems.Count; i++) {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems[i].Selected) {
            int i2 = listView1.SelectedItems[i].Index;
            item = listView1.Items[i2].Text;
            sColl.Add(item);
        }
    }
}

listView1.SelectedItems.Clear();
foreach (var itemS in sColl)
{
    string items = itemS;
}
 sColl.Clear();
listView1.SelectedItems.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't bring back the SelectedIndex ? Add this extension after your current namespace.

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static int SelectedIndex(this ListView listView)
    {
        if (listView.SelectedIndices.Count > 0)
            return listView.SelectedIndices[0];
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Encapsulate this class in a namespace called Extensions and then add this inside your projects namespace to use the extension.

```
  using Extensions;
```

Then simply use like this

```
   private void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int selectionindex = ListView1.SelectedIndex();
        ListViewItem seletedItem = ListView1.Items[selectionindex];           
    }
```

P.S.
The extension method should have returned -1 on Else, but as long as you're using it from the SelectedIndexChanged event, you're fine as it won't get fired if there are no items. 
This is by design, as the SelectedIndexChanged event gets fired twice. Once to deselect the initial item, then to select the new one.
Proper way is to return -1 and check for negative numer.
This is also why someone here got and ArgumentOutOfRange Exception.

Comment: This is a WPF question, not a winforms question. [The WPF ListView control inherits SelectedIndex form Selector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx). It's quite possible that somebody trying to do the same thing in winforms may end up here and find your answer useful, but you should at least make a note of the distinction in your answer.

Comment: Since the convention for SelectedIndex is to return either -1 if nothing is selected, or the index of the selected item, there is no valid value representing that multiple items are selected, thus its removal.