# Get Index of Listview ot ListViewItem from PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listviewitem

So I have `ListView` with `MyData` object.
And once I click the Left mouse key without release (so the item is not selected yet) I want to get my item (`ListViewItem` or just the `ListViewItem` index...)

So this is what I have tried:

```
ListView listView;

private void listView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = e.Source;
    MyData myData = (MyData)(sender as ListView).SelectedItem;
    if (myData!= null)
    {
        // Do my stuff...
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, because the `ListViewItem` is not selected yet my `myData` is always `null`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's a possible [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21327931/get-the-index-of-item-selected-in-listview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking `((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext`.